# Boost installation failed : cannot find -lrt

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I had a trouble when I install the boost library(1.59.0) on my ubuntu 14.04.
I have executed ./b2 like the following:

`./b2 install --exec-prefix=/usr/local --libdir=/root/boost/lib/ --includedir=/root/boost/include/ --with-system`

But I have an error like this:

`...found 22664 targets...
...updating 3 targets...
gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-   multi/libboost_system.so.1.59.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status "g++" -o "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.59.0" -Wl,-h -Wl,libboost_system.so.1.59.0 -shared -Wl,--start-group "bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/error_code.o"  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lrt -Wl,--end-group -march=i686 -pthread -m32 
...failed gcc.link.dll bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.3.3/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.59.0...`

How can I fix it? `cannot find -lrt` but I have `librt-2.11.1.so` in the `/lib` directory.

Thanks.

Comment: is there .so link in `/lib` to that lib?

Comment: seems you are building for 32 bits, are you sure you installed the 32 bit version of the lib as well (If your host is 64 bits)

Comment: Yeah, librt.so.1, which linked to librt-2.11.1.so, exists in `/lib`. And it also supports x86.

Answer (score 1):

`librt-2.11.1.so` file is for runtime, for linking there should be `.so` symbolic link. Looks like you have package that installs `rt` but you missing dev package that provides necessary `.so` links. Did you install `build-essential` meta package?

Comment: I have installed build-essential but it didn't work correct. So I modified the gcc.jam in the boost source and remove the requiring line of rt library. And it worked correct.